# How do i change the css of the selected item in the state on clicking -- React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

HI i am trying to make a todo application in React Native.
I am trying to change css of an item when user clicks on it. PFB the code for the sam. Let me know what i am doing wrong.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  StatusBar,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    inputValue: '',
    todos: [],
  };

  changeText = value => {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: value,
    });
  };

  addItem = () => {
    if (this.state.inputValue !== '') {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        const newToDo = {
          title: this.state.inputValue,
          isSelected: false,
          createdAt: Date.now(),
        };

        var todos = this.state.todos.concat(newToDo);

        this.setState({
          inputValue: '',
          todos: todos,
        });
      });
    }
  };

  markTodo = (ev) => {
    let todo = this.state.todos;
    let item = todo.indexOf(ev);
    todo[item].isSelected = true;
    this.setState({todos: todo});
  }

  render() {
    const todos = this.state.todos.reverse().map((todo, key) => (
      <View style={[{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 20 }, todo.isSelected ? {color: "red"} : {color: "white"}]}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.markTodo(todo)}
          style={{
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            borderRadius: 15,
            borderWidth: 3,
            borderColor: 'white',
            margin: 25,
          }}
        />
        <Text
          style={{
            paddingLeft: 5,
            marginTop: 10,
            fontSize: 28,
            color: 'white',
          }}>
          {todo.title}
        </Text>
      </View>
    ));

    return (
      <LinearGradient colors={['#667eea', '#764ba2']} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        <View>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            onSubmitEditing={this.addItem}
            onChangeText={this.changeText}
            placeholder="Type here to add a to do."
            value={this.state.inputValue}
            placeholderTextColor={'#fff'}
            multiline={true}
            autoCapitalize="sentences"
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            selectionColor={'white'}
            maxLength={30}
            returnKeyType="done"
            autoCorrect={false}
            blurOnSubmit={true}
          />
        </View>
        <View>{todos}</View>
      </LinearGradient>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  input: {
    marginTop: 30,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingRight: 15,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    fontSize: 34,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
};
```

I am trying to call a function when the user clicks on Touchable opacity and then try to change the css for that item itself but the function markTodo() is getting triggered even while i am typing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your function here.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>this.markTodo(todo)}
```

And then in you textInput component function do this :
 `onChangeText={text=> this.setState({ inputValue : text}) }`

So basically it sums up to :

```
 <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            onSubmitEditing={this.addItem}
          onChangeText={text=> this.setState({ inputValue : text}) }
            placeholder="Type here to add a to do."
            value={this.state.inputValue}
            placeholderTextColor={'#fff'}
            multiline={true}
            autoCapitalize="sentences"
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            selectionColor={'white'}
            maxLength={30}
            returnKeyType="done"
            autoCorrect={false}
            blurOnSubmit={true}
          />
```

Comment: HI binding <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>this.markTodo(todo)} solved my click issue but i am still not able to change the css of the selected item

Comment: I can't see any of your code that would work for the selected item. To make that work use a boolean value which would be saved in the state and when thats true or false use inline styles to show the selected/dis selected item.

Comment: Hi thankyou for responding i am doing that in the markTodo() function